# Flareget Browser Integration

Tags: google-chrome

I want to integrate flareget to Google Chrome. Flareget says I need to download browser integration plugin from the website. When I click on it, I see the following: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

So how to I integrate flareget to my Chrome browser now?

Comment: How does this question have anything to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flareget has moved to a new domain. Just go to http://flareget.com and click browser integration from the header menu. You can get plugin from their.  Perhaps the direct link is http://flareget.com/browser-integration-2